# Elasticsearch _msearch not working on aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get distinct values for several fields at one request.

When I try to get distinct values for one field, everything works perfectly:

```
GET shakespeare/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "speaker",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to call several queries with _msearch, everything also works:

```
GET shakespeare/_msearch
{}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "size":2, "from":10}
{}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "size":2}
```

But as soon as I try to merge this, it fails:

```
GET shakespeare/_msearch
{}
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "speaker",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
{}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "size":2}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "Exception when parsing search request"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "Exception when parsing search request",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "json_parse_exception",
      "reason": "Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@1a0c4712; line: 1, column: 23]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? Should I somehow wrap aggs in a query?

Is there any other way of doing it?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Query in a single line like this:

```
GET shakespeare/_msearch
{}
{"size": 0,"aggs": {"NAME": {"terms": {"field": "speaker","size": 1000}}}}
{}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "size":2}
```

Even normal queries(without aggregation) fail if they contain `\n`. It's because of the API format:

```
header\n
body\n
header\n
body\n
```

It considers `\n` as delimiter. The following example will also fail.

```
GET shakespeare/_msearch
{}
{
 "query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "size":2, "from":10}
{}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "size":2}
```